# Grid in Itemscontrol - WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, grid

I have problem when using Grid in ItemsControl. Here is my code:

```
 <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Image Name="imgCotrol"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Source="{Binding Image}"
                                       Margin="0,10,0,10"/>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"           
                                           Name="txtControl"  
                                           Text="{Binding Description}"  
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>  
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                        
                </ItemsControl>
```

The problem here is that the Grid.RowDefinitions are not affecting the remaining space. The Image control overflows the TextBlock control in some cases.I think the ItemTemplate ignores the Grid rows. I read somewhere that ContentPresenter from the ItemsControl is causing this behavior. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: can you show a print screen of what is happening.

Comment: A long shot, but might it be the image itself is overflowing into the next row because its too big? Try setting the `Stretch` property to different values (uniform is default) or testing the control with a smaller image?

Comment: I don't think the image is the problem because of the RowDefinition Height="*".
The problem is that the ItemTemplate can't recognize the Rows from the Grid, because of the ContentPresenter. I need workaround for this.

Comment: your error is in <RowDefinition Height="*"/>                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/> . You should put the first row or the second with Auto or a defined height!

Comment: try putting a border tag around the grid to be shore the text is outside the grid and is not anything else.

Comment: I added border tag and the image still overflows, the text is not shown.